# Android: Accessing string.xml using variable name

Tags: android, resources

I want to display a message to the user depending upon a prompt I receive from another part of the program. There can be a number of prompts & they are stored in an enum.

These are my prompts:

**Defs.java**

```
public enum Prompt
{
    PromptA,
    PromptB,
    PromptC,
}
```

I have the externalized strings stored in resources on these lines:

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="PromptA">Error in execution</string>
<string name="PromptB">Process completed successfully</string>
<string name="PromptC">Please try again</string>
```

Now in my **main Activity** screen a method is called by some other part:

```
public void showPrompt(Prompt prompt) {
    String message = getString(R.string.<**what-do-I-put-here?**>);
    //show a dialog box with message
}
```

I know this can be done with a huge if-else block (there are tons of prompts in the actual application) or a switch statement. 
It will be really ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538649/accessing-contents-of-r-string-using-a-variable-to-represent-the-resource-name/7189023#7189023

Comment: @OceanBlue: Can't you use a [string array resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) indexed by `prompt.ordinal()`? Using `ordinal` is generally not recommended, as it may be fragile in case you reorder or add an item, but there are many more fragile things when using XML.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See `Resources.getIdentifier`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 . You can try something like this:

```
public void showPrompt(Prompt prompt, String label) {
    String message = (String) getResources().getText(getResources().getIdentifier(label, "string", null));
    //show a dialog box with message
}
```

Try that out and see what that does for you.

EDIT: meh. Try this instead.

```
public void showPrompt(Prompt prompt, String label) {
    String message = (String) getResources().getText(getResources().getIdentifier(label, "string", "<application package class>"));
    //show a dialog box with message
}
```

Turns out you have to specify the your package identifier (so if your AndroidManifest.xml has **com.blah.blah.blah** as the Package put that in the third parameter.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I did notice in the link that you've added: "*Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.*" So are the only choices in this fairly common situation, to write **inefficient** code or **ugly, unmaintainable** code. :-(   Wish Google would add this capability to resources.

Comment: It is *discouraged*, but not *deprecated*; driving fast is discouraged as well, but not deprecated :). It is definitely more efficient doing it by resource id, but if you have a few instances where you wish to look up id by string name this is provided for you. **If it was not to be used at all it would not have been provided**. Or you could write your massive switch statement: your choice.

Comment: Fair enough. At least this is an alternative to using the switch statement.

Comment: Use context.getPackageName() for the package parameter.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. I don't understand why it doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is just enclose the line in a if/else if/else statement, or a switch.

```
String message;
switch(prompt) {
case PromptA:
    message = getString(R.string.PromptA);
    break;
case PromptB:
    message = getString(R.string.PromptB);
    break;
case PromptC:
    message = getString(R.string.PromptC);
    break;
default:
    message = "";
}
```

I'm not on the machine I usually develop on, so there may be some silly syntax error in there, but the logic 'should' work.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am doing, but as I mentioned in my question.. this is getting pretty big & ugly since there are so many prompts. Also, in future if a prompt is added, I'd rather not change the code, just the xml.