# Android: Dynamic Button Names

Tags: android, json, button

I want to change the text on some buttons dynamically. 
All necessary text is saved at the strings.xml and the reference name is saved in a Json Object.

Anyone knows how i can get the data from strings.xml for my setText function?

```
JSONObject e = Options.getJSONObject(i); 
//The Name for strings.xml
String name = e.getString("name");

Resources res = getResources();
button1.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.string. ??????????? )));
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157887/r-string-get-string-from-dynamic-key-name

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this

```
getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", “com.main.package”));
```

or better:

```
getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the any string from String.xml by

```
 getString(R.string.string_name);
```