# How to dynamically generate the raw resource identifier in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a mobile library app. I have a 3-4 db files of books stored in raw folder. If I know the name of the book then I first copy this file to /databases/book_name.db and then access them as required. I use

```
InputStream fileInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.book_name);
```

for accessing these files.

Now, I want to pass the book name and then dynamically generate the resource identifier R.raw.book_name using the string book_name. Is there a way by which I can generate this identifier?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/book_name", null, this.getPackageName());
```

If your code not in activity or application, you need to get Context first.

```
Context context = getContext(); // or getBaseContext(), or getApplicationContext()
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/book_name", null, context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Just a hint, if you have a file with extension, for example: `raw/list_users.json` then do not include extension `.json`, simple: `getResources().getIdentifier("list_users", "raw", "<application package class>")` do a trick.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the answer I gave here: [Android: Accessing string.xml using variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980577/android-accessing-string-xml-using-variable-name)

Try:

```
int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier(bookname, "raw", "<application package class>");
```

EDIT: meh, its raw.

Answer (score 1):

*Based off of Sergey's answer.*

I'm using this in a CursorAdapter to DRY up the code and the final version that worked was:

```
String attribute   = "company_name";
String packageName = view.getContext().getPackageName();

int resourceId = view.getResources().getIdentifier(attribute, null, packageName);
```

Actually, this was causing me problems so I switched to the following, which seemed more stable:

```
int resourceId = R.id.class.getField(attribute).getInt(null);
```