# Trying to get a resource id for media file within fragment

Tags: android, resources, fragment

I'm trying to get a resource id for a mp3 file within a fragment and I can't find out how to do this.  The following code returns zero for the resource id. Yes, the file is there in the raw directory.  (I'm using ActionBarSherlock, but I'm not sure that matters.)

```
public class NavigationFragment extends SherlockFragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View nav =inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation, container, false);
  } 

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier("bell01", "raw", "com.webnation.yogatest");
        Log.d("We're Here", "resourceID =" + resourceID);

        bell = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), resourceID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    }
  } //onActivityCreated

}
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.webnation.yogatest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.webnation.yogatest.YogaTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EulaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_eula_activity" >
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder[/link] didn't help me.

Comment: can you post your manifest ?

Comment: and a screenshot of your raw folder ?

Comment: can you replace the hardcoded context name by getPackageName() ?

Comment: This post is for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222758/how-to-dynamically-generate-the-raw-resource-identifier-in-android

Comment: btw, android:targetSdkVersion="17" is better

Comment: That answer didn't help, unfortunately.  The problem is that I'm trying to find a resource from within a fragment.  Eclipse gave me a compile error when I used getPackageName().