# Android button soundboard

Tags: android, audio, media, playback

I'm trying to make a soundboard app, but I'm running into a problem with handling the sound files. More specifically I do not know how to get it so when a button is pressed it plays a corresponding sound back.

I've tried using this way
 [Play sound on button click android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459122/play-sound-on-button-click-android)

I tried implementing a media player for each sound file and button but the app crashes on start up.

I have 10 buttons with 10 corresponding sound files that are located in the raw file in src/res/raw/

Any idea on how to make it work?

```
//this is a breaking bad soundboard app, so please excuse the language. Sorry if you      find it offensive
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    whatup = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    haveatit = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    hello = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    whining = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    money = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    yeah= (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    miserable = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    mother = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button9);
    gatorade = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    science = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button10);

    whatup.setOnClickListener(this);
    haveatit.setOnClickListener(this);
    hello.setOnClickListener(this);
    whining.setOnClickListener(this);
    money.setOnClickListener(this);
    yeah.setOnClickListener(this);
    miserable.setOnClickListener(this);
    mother.setOnClickListener(this);
    gatorade.setOnClickListener(this);
    science.setOnClickListener(this);

    WhatUp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.whatupb);
    HaveAtIt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.haveatit);
    Hello = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hello);
    Whining = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.stopwhining);
    Money = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.wheresmymoney);
    Yeah = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.yeahb);
    Miserable = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.miserableb);
    Mother = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.motherofgod);
    Gatorade = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gatorade);
    Science = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.yeahscience);

}
```

this is for handling when the button is pressed. Obviously there needs to be more, but I was just testing 1 button and it crashes when I try starting it.

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view==whatup)
    {
        WhatUp.start();
    }
}
```

Log Cat Errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz4Sz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I assume your sounds might be `sound_1`, `sound_2`, `sound_3`, etc. and your buttons are `button_1`, `button_2` and so on..
You should create a loop to get the ids in `onCreate` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // get the id for buttons
    int btnId = getResources().getIdentifier("button_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    // get the res for sounds
    int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier("sound_"+i, "raw", getPackageName());
    // set a click listener to all your buttons
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
    button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // create the media player with the raw id
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, rawId);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // avoid NullPointerException see the links below
                    mp.release();
                }
            });   
            // play the sound
            mp.start();
         }
    });
}
```

Read the topic reference: [Using MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer). You could also get identifer with the context: [How to dynamically generate the raw resource identifier in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222819/2668136) and this might help you for explanation of `release()` method: [Play sound on button click - Null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3369068/2668136) and read the `Releasing the MediaPlayer` part from [Using MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer).  I'm not sure but it should do the trick..
Good luck.

---

**UPDATE**

Change this check `if(view==whatup)` to `if(view.getId() == R.id.button)`.
In `onClick` method you need to check the id regarding the view, with `getId()` method.

Comment: This looks helpful. I just found an article that says I should use a soundpool instead of a media player. Do you know the differences?

Comment: I've just read the contrary: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/ -Awesome! ^^

Comment: I switched it over and It still crashes on Start up. Here is my code that I have for onCreate

Comment: Add the `LogCat` in your question.

Comment: Added log cat. I couldn't copy the code over so I just took a screen shot

Comment: Line 62 in your activity.. you have a `nullpointerexception`. What's is it in the line?

Comment: Right at the beginning where I assign listeners to my buttons. It's the first button I assign a listener to
whatup.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Hum.. is it the right id in your layout for findViewById(R.id.button)? Isn't it `button1`?

Comment: I have no idea. This is my first time coding in Android Studio. It has to be the way I set up the layout. Usually I use Eclipse with the android sdk. 

So far I am not a fan with android studio. I have encountered a lot of issues with migrating.

I think my best bet would be to rewrite the code for the layout.

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Well, I think you should have the same structure (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#Project) as Eclipse, your layout might be in `/res/layout/`