# Android development: how to access a string when the ID is in a variable?

Tags: java, android

Okay, so in my project, I want to be able to change what string from string.xml is used for a specific thing based on a variable which contains the string ID. Ideally I'd be able to do something like this

```
thing.setText(R.id.variablename)
```

and if variablename was equal to "question1", it'd end up being equivalent to

```
thing.setText(R.id.question1)
```

But that obviously doesn't work, as it instead looks for a string whose ID is variablename. Is there any way for me to do what I want to do here? The alternative to this would be to make a separate instance in my app for every question, and that would be silly given how every single page would be completely identical other than the strings being used being different.

Comment: Java: thing.setText(getResources.getString(R.id.variablename)) Kotlin:         thing.text = resources.getString(R.id.variablename)

Comment: You may look this question, I think explains your problem and have different approaches to the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538649/accessing-contents-of-r-string-using-a-variable-to-represent-the-resource-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing contents of R.string using a variable to represent the resource name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538649/accessing-contents-of-r-string-using-a-variable-to-represent-the-resource-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
  String packageName = getPackageName();
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
  return getString(resId);
}


thing.setText(getStringResourceByName("question1"));
```

Or simply the one liner

```
getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier("question1", "string", getPackageName()))
```